# Java EJB transactions and transactional resources

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

How does transaction manager know when we are participating with a transactional resource and it needs to be specially handled? For example:

method in an EJB:

```
public void doStuff() {
  persistentManager.doWork(); // needs to be rolled back/commmited
  somefield2.doWork(); // doesnt participate in roll back/commit
  System.out.println("x"); // doesnt participate in roll back/commit
  jmsStuff.doWork(); // needs to be rolled back/commmited
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an EntityManager, the application server or JPA provider will enlist a callback with the current transaction context using TransactionSynchronizationRegistry or (equivalent internal API) to be notified just before the transaction commits so that it can use the underlying resource (a JDBC DataSource) to do the actual work.

When you look up or use a JDBC resource, the application server registers the resource with the TransactionManager so it can be completed when the transaction is committed/rolledback.  The exact details are unspecified, but it might use JCA under the covers.

When you look up a JCA resource (such as JMS), the JCA specification has the details on how the application server interacts with the resource provider to be notified for transaction completion (for example, the XAResource interface).

Answer (score 0):

Through [transaction annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).  These allow the programmer to declaratively define the transaction behaviour of EJB components.  This means you can instruct `persistentManager.doWork()` that it should enlist in the current transaction, and `somefield2.doWork()` that it should start its own (or run without a transaction at all.

For more complex scenarios you can also use [Bean Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html), which allow programmatic control over transactional behaviour for more obscure requirements.

Comment: Ok, Lets suppose I want to build my own thing (transactional resource), how can I make global transaction manager know about it inside EJB methods ans enlist it inside transaction?

Comment: I don't know of any easy way to make a whole new transactional resource.  I believe to do this you'd need some low level interaction with the container and the JTA to handle scenarios like two-phase commits.